# Magento - Error after disabling modules

Tags: magento-1.7, magento

I've disabled the Rss and Newsletter modules of my Magento 1.7 instance following the instructions of this post:

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/how-to-fully-disable-turn-off-magento-module/comment-page-1/#comment-65853

I just edited the `app\etc\modules\Mage_All.xml` file by changing to `<active>false</active>` in both `Mage_Rss` and `Mage_Newsletter` modules.

The problem is that when I try to load a customer page through admin panel, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function loadByCustomer() on a
>   non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber.php on
>   line 267

Why is it happening? Why is this code being executing even though I've disabled such module?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I could solve the problem (not sure if generated any side effect):

Just edited the file `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Customer\Edit\Tabs.php` around line 90 by adding the external if clause:

```
        if (Mage::helper('core')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Newsletter')) {
            if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('newsletter/subscriber')) {
                        $this->addTab('newsletter', array(
                            'label'     => Mage::helper('customer')->__('Newsletter'),
                            'content'   => $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/customer_edit_tab_newsletter')->initForm()->toHtml()
                        ));
                    }
        }
```

+1 if I saved your day and please let me know if you noticed and possible impact :D

Comment: Since it's testing if the Newsletter is allowed, turning the newsletter off in System Config under the newsletter entries probably would have eliminated the error. Your test for the module load will keep someone from turning it on down the road and resurrecting the issue so it's a valid method. Just as a sidenote, check the app/etc/module xml file for the Customer module and see if Newsletter is listed as a dependency.

Comment: As to side effects, now you start to think how the Newsletter module is used. Since it is disabled, its configuration no longer references the layout specific to that module and therefore shouldn't call any templates specific to that module. That means that the frontend shouldn't give you any issues. I'm guessing that since Newsletter was one of those early central items intended to be in Magento, that testing in the Admin section for it being disabled got missed. That means checking any area (other than the newsletter tab which should no longer show) where it might be found in customer maint.

Answer (score 3):

**First step after disabling a module through its `<active>` entry. Always clear cache and** if you use the compiler, **recompile so you don't have code referencing classes in the disabled module.**

Often the problem is not with code executing after the module is shut off through the app/etc/modules/mod_name.xml by setting `<active>` to false, but with other modules, templates or layouts attempting to call code in the disabled module.

Where issues come in are if **another module lists the module** just turned off **in its dependency list**. Always check all the other module xml files dependency lists for mention of the module you are deactivating.

Also, you have to check for template `.phtml` files that reference classes in the disabled module. This can throw the dreaded `call to a non-object` type exception errors. As an example, one module that provides custom cart attributes asks you to add entries to your cart templates. Shutting off the module does not get rid of the references.

Make sure no layouts are attempting to load anything referencing this module as well (custom layout local.xml).

You also might want to go to System Config, Advanced and shut the Newsletter module output off there in case the Magento Customer Account is depending on testing for the module being disabled by calling that entry instead of actually checking to see if the Module is loaded. Sometimes Magento programmers forget to do proper error trapping, which has thrown me for a loop before.

Comment: Thanks @fiasco-labs. Actually, I've already executed your tips before creating this question. The module I disabled is not a dependency to any other module.

Comment: I put the answer up because the question is a common problem and while it wasn't a direct answer, it is a kind of diagnosis decision tree that needs to be followed out to start thinking on module interaction and where the current code may be making function calls to the disabled module. As you found, **sometimes dependencies can be hidden** and then you add your own code to test for that module. It's a process I've had to follow out several times. As to side effects... comment on your answer.